# Can "do" substitute -ing form?

Tags: verbs

The following is the sentence from the textbook:

> Attorneys are taught to "steal the opponent's thunder" by mentioning a weakness in their case before the opposing lawyer **does**.

I was wondering whether "does" substitutes "mentioning a weakness in their case" or "steal the opponent's thunder by mentioning a weakness in their case". My textbook says the former, but can "do" substitue "by -ing" form? For me, the latter makes more sense.

Comment: "before the opposing lawyer does (it)". *it* being "to steal the opponent's thunder by mentioning a weakness in their case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a question of whether *do* can substitute for an -ing form  but of reading from context.

The best interpretation for *does* is "*mentions the weakness*".  This is because the context is [**stealing someone's thunder**, an idiom which means "to take someone else's idea" or "to destroy the effect of what someone else does by doing it first."](https://www.bloomsbury-international.com/en/student-ezone/idiom-of-the-week/117-steal-someones-thunder.html)

So the advice to lawyers is to steal the opponent's thunder by mentioning the weakness first: if they mention the weakness first, it won't have much effect if the opponent brings it up later.  It doesn't make sense to think of the *opponent* as "stealing someone's thunder", because they're not taking your idea, you're taking theirs.

To address the question more generally, *do* can substitute for an -ing form, but usually not directly or without changing the structure a bit.  For example, you could say

> I am **taking** this candy before the children **do**

but you wouldn't literally write

> I am taking this candy before the children taking it

or

> I am taking this candy before the children are taking it

You would have to write

> I am taking this candy before the children **take it**